# Are games released for xbox One still downloadable onto xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, backwards-compatibility

I'm aware that the Xbox One can play several Xbox 360 games. Can I currently purchase, download, and play games created for the Xbox One **specifically** through the Xbox 360 store?

Comment: We can't answer this; this is the future you're asking about, and we have no idea what will happen. We don't allow questions about the future of the industry. We deal with the here and now.

Comment: I figured since the xbox One is out and people have it, someone would know. I've seen similar questions asked about the switch from xbox to xbox 360, I was hoping to find something similar with this console update.

Comment: I'm unclear on what this is asking. Do you want to buy and play One games on the 360?

Comment: @Rapitor yes but not buy a hard copy, if that makes sense. can I still buy/download games from the online store and play without issues on a 360? or does that also change when a new console is released? Im realizing this may be a no brainer, but i just don't know and was hoping to get some clarification.

Comment: One games cannot be played on the 360, they can only be played on the One. Conversely, only a select amount of 360 games can be played on the One, with more games being added continuously.

Comment: I suggest editing for succinctness, into something like maybe "Games for the Xbox 360 will stop being made in 2016. I'm aware that the Xbox One can play several Xbox 360 games. Will I be able to purchase and play games created for the Xbox One through the Xbox 360 store?". (I didn't make the edit myself since it seems a bit drastic.)

Comment: @Schism Yeah that's a good idea, I'm trying to avoid asking about future events/scenarios since they don't allow questions about the future of the industry apparently. I'll still fix it up to reflect the present as much as I can. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: As it stands, this is currently an answerable, objective question, well within our means to answer. Well done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the Xbox One can now play a small amount of 360 games (with more being added to support over time), the 360 cannot play Xbox One games. There wouldn't be much point to upgrading consoles if the old out of date hardware can play the new games now would there?

Comment: Got it, thank you for the answer. I was curious to see if there was value in keeping a 360 to play only downloaded games (and just forego buying hard copies anymore) but thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: You wouldn't need to buy hard copies with the One if that means anything, its digital store is "better" than the 360's.

Comment: If i were to hang on to a 360 to continue buying and playing older games released for the 360, do you know if i would still be able to use the digital store? for example, if i didnt want to buy the hard copy, could i still download and play the new tomb raider on my 360?

Comment: as long as it's the 360 version yeah there is no issues.